# Failed to create the pipeline. Google push to deploy

Tags: google-compute-engine

Hi I just create a new project in Google App Engine.

I wanted to use the release pipeline with the option of building and testing {python nosetest option}. I have connected the repository with bitbucket. I tried to move source control from bitbucket to the default google source control option. There does not seem to be any difference.

When I try to create the pipeline I get the following error.

[image]

Failed to create the pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.

You need to initialize compute-engine VM first. I created a project and did not initialize compute-engine.

Comment: I get this error even when using the Python source option, which does not require a compute-engine VM.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue about it not working here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10952